# iAdBanner not appears on iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, position, constraints

I have an iADBanner at the bottom of the screen. When i run my app on iOS 8, it works like a charm. But when I run the app on iOS 7 it doesn't appear.

When I clear the constraints for the iADBanner and only put a constraint to position it at the bottom, the iAdBanner appear in both iOS versions, but Xcode show me a "Missing constraints: Missing position X" If I put the position X, we return to the problem that iADBanner is not showing on iOS 7.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work for me for iOS 7 and 8:

In viewDidLoad:

> ```
> _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height, 320, 50)];
> _adBanner.delegate = self;
> [_adBanner setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
> ```

And methods:

```
 - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
        if (!_bannerIsVisible) {
        // If banner isn't part of view hierarchy, add it
        if (_adBanner.superview == nil) {
             [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
         }

         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

         // Assumes the banner view is just off the bottom of the screen.
          banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

         [UIView commitAnimations];

         _bannerIsVisible = YES;
     }
 }


 - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

     if (_bannerIsVisible)
     {
         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

         // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
         banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

         [UIView commitAnimations];

         _bannerIsVisible = NO;
     }
 }
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, 95% the solution that i needed!